# IOS: How to get CLLocationManager alert when user declined

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, cllocationmanager

How to enable `CLLocationManager` alert whenever open my app if user declined. Can anybody tell how ?

```
        locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I need to show this alert once they opens my app again.

[image]

Comment: It's only showed once, the only thing you can do it to show a new alertview telling the user to go to settings app and give permissions to your app

Comment: @jcesar make that your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location permission alert is only displayed once. If the user has denied permission to your app, then they will have to enable location services in **Settings > Privacy > Location Services**. See [Understanding Location Services](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5594) by Apple for more information.

In your code, you should check the value of `+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW11)) - if the status is `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`, you can prompt the user to re-enable Location Services in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If the user declines this dialog, your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s `-locationManager:didFailWithError:` callback will get an `NSError` with:

- domain: kCLErrorDomain
- code: kCLErrorDenied

You can handle that error appropriately.